# sqlx return empty struct even if it exist

Tags: go, sqlx

Here is my code  :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "log"
    "time"
)

type Commune struct {
    Id int `db:"id"`
    Created time.Time `db:"created"`
    Modified time.Time `db:"modified"`
    Name string `db:"name"`
}

func main() {
    var err error
    db, err = sqlx.Connect("postgres", "user=toto 
    dbname=tata password=titi sslmode=disable")
    commune := []Commune{}
    db.Select(&commune, `SELECT * FROM "Geo_commune"  WHERE id=1  ORDER BY name ASC`)
    rows, err2 := db.Query(`SELECT * FROM "Geo_commune"  WHERE id=1  ORDER BY name ASC`)
    fmt.Println(commune)
    fmt.Println(rows)
    if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
    }
     if err2 != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err2)
    }

   }
```

here is the data in the database :

[image]

edit : the table_name :

[image]

and i've even tried with :

```
db.Select(&commune, `SELECT * FROM "Geo_commune"  WHERE id=1  ORDER BY name ASC`)
```

but the return is always empty and i'am sure that the data exists and i don't have a connection error.

Without the `"Geo_commune"` 
 rows, err2 := db.Query(`SELECT * FROM Geo_commune  WHERE id=1  ORDER BY name ASC`)
i have a : 
2019/01/28 22:17:16 pq: relation "geo_commune" does not exist

Regards

edit my new tests :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "log"
    "time"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)
type Commune struct {
    Id int `db:"id"`
    Created time.Time `db:"created"`
    Modified time.Time `db:"modified"`
    Name string `db:"name"`

}
var db *sqlx.DB
func main() {
    var err error
    db, err = sqlx.Connect("postgres", "user=toto dbname=titi password=tata sslmode=disable")
    commune := []Commune{}

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    db.Select(&commune, `SELECT * FROM "Geo_commune"  WHERE id=1  ORDER BY name ASC`)
    rows, err2 := db.Query(`SELECT * FROM "Geo_commune"  WHERE id=1  ORDER BY name ASC`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err2)
    }


    db.Select(&commune, `SELECT * FROM public.Geo_commune  WHERE id=1  ORDER BY name ASC`)
    rows, err2 = db.Query(`SELECT * FROM public.Geo_commune  WHERE id=1  ORDER BY name ASC`)
    fmt.Println(commune)
    fmt.Println(rows)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err2)
    }



    }
```

gives me :

```
[]
<nil>
2019/01/29 09:50:06 pq: relation "public.geo_commune" does not exist
```

Comment: Don't ignore the error returned by Select.

Comment: @Peteri've edited and no error ....

Comment: What is the name of the table? (Try without quoting it)

Comment: @pete Geo_commune but nope it's not working

Comment: Your table seems to have much more columns than your struct has fields, wouldn't that be a problem when using `SELECT * ...`? Did you try a listing the four columns that have corresponding fields in the Commune struct? [This test](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/blob/master/sqlx_test.go#L275-L281) seems to suggest that `Select` should return an error if you're missing a "destination" field, and in the code you provided you're not checking that specific error, since the result of your `db.Select` call isn't assigned to anything.

Comment: You're still not checking the error returned from `db.Select`, why? And what's the purpose of `db.Query` in your code? Use only one, not both.

Comment: @mpkopriva you're right it's that thanks , i miss some fields in my struct and i didn't truly checked the error of select

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused with your description.
did it throw `pq: relation "geo_commune" does not exist`?
if it did, your datasource is incorrect.
if it didn't,  try `select * from public.Geo_commune`

Comment: i have a 2019/01/29 09:29:13 pq: relation "public.geo_commune" does not exist error because my table is Geo_commune